# How to simulate a click on a jQuery-UI modal dialog button with Capybara?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, rspec, capybara

In a Web application, I use a jQueryUI modal dialog to confirm an action:

```
function erase() {
  $("#dialog").text("Are you sure want to delete this record?")
  .attr("title", "Delete...")
  .dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
      Delete: function() {
        $.ajax({
          ...snip...
          success: function() {
            self.location = "."; // returns to the welcome page
          }
        });
      },
      ...snip...
    }
  });
}
```

The code works pretty well, but I couldn't succeed in testing it with Capybara:

```
...snip...
Capybara.default_driver = :webkit
...snip...

def in_dialog()
  f = find('.ui-dialog')
end

feature 'Delete a record' do
...snip...
  scenario 'for any record' do
    click_on 'Delete...'
    page.should have_content 'Are you sure want to delete this record?'
    in_dialog.click_button 'Delete'
    page.should have_content 'Welcome'
    ...snip...
  end
end
```

Capybara finds the button but everything goes as if the callback were never fired.

I tried different workarounds (several of which I found on stackoverflow):

- sleep,
- "wait for ajax",
- page.native.send_keys(:return) instead of click_button 'Delete',
- find('button', :text => 'Delete').click instead of click_button 'Delete',
- Selenium driver instead of webkit driver.

None worked. Any other idea?

Comment: Could you post a reproduction case (if it's large for SO, then to e.g. gist.github.com)?

Comment: Here is a gist of the capybara scenario interacting with my test server : https://gist.github.com/4547091

Comment: Please, prepare a reproduction case including relevant HTML/JS files. How do you expect us to tell how to fix issue if I don't know how to reproduce it?

Comment: The scenario includes the URL of the server. You just have to run it.

Comment: Regarding `select 'invitation', :from => 'aeresType'`. There's nothing with text `invitation` in this select box

Comment: I've tried to follow those steps in browser manually. But after clicking button in browser nothing happens (server returns 409 error)

Comment: Oh, crap, you're right. The scenario was not exactly the same as the one I tested by hand, and it was bugged. I will check that the test passes once the bug is fixed but I'm nearly sure you got the solution.

Comment: You may write it as a solution so that I can award the bounty to you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You posted [code that you use to interact with the server](https://gist.github.com/4547091) in comments.

I followed those steps manually in browser but click on the button "Supprimer" returns 409 error and nothing else happens. That's why nothing happens in your test when you click this button.

Comment: I must admit that the Capybara scenario was not exactly the same as the one I tested by hand, and the former failed because of an unreported bug. It seems that I was too confident in the application, and not enough in Capybara-jQueryUI integration. Now that the bug is fixed, the scenario runs fine. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, sleep should have at least worked, but here is what I use to make sure my AJAX call has returned:

```
in_dialog.click_button 'Delete'
wait_until { page.evaluate_script("jQuery.active") == 0 }
page.should have_content 'Welcome'
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This seems similar to what I tried earlier but I'll have another try.

Comment: Hmm, it didn't work :(
Did anyone have any success with Capybara on jQueryUI?

Comment: `wait_until` is deprecated and it is removed from capybara 2.0, you shouldn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

You could always execute custom javascript code inside capybara's scenario. Did you try something like:

```
# when
page.execute_script("$('.the-button-selector').click();")
# then
page.should_not have_css(".the-dialog-selector")
```